# Евклидова геометрия. Расстояние от точки до отрезка

Tags: c++, математика, геометрия

Заданы координаты двух точек. Они описывают отрезок.
Заданы координаты ещё одной точки.

Найти расстояние от отрезка до точки.

Суть проблемы: Проходит не все тесты при явно верном математическом решении.

Код:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define sqr(a) ((a)*(a))
typedef long double ld;


ld d(ld x, ld y, ld a, ld b, ld c)
{
    return (abs(a*x + b*y + c) / sqrt(a*a + b*b));
}



int main()

{
    ifstream cin("input.txt");

    int x, y, x1, y1, x2, y2;
    long double a, b, c;

    cin >> x >> y >> x1 >> y1 >> x2 >> y2;

    a = (y2 - y1);
    b = (x1 - x2);
    c = (x2*y1 - x1*y2);

    cout << fixed << setprecision(60) << abs(d(x, y, a, b, c)) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Полагаю, проблемы точно не в коэффицентах. Этот вариант я проверял, количество пройденных тестов не менялось.

Тестирующая система: http://informatics.mccme.ru/mod/statements/view3.php?chapterid=279

Comment: "от отрезка до точки" или "от прямой до точки"?

Comment: О отрезка. Опечатка.

Comment: И еще. Чтобы разобраться в чем там дело, я должен у них регистрироваться? По-моему, Вы ожидаете слишком много усилий со стороны тех, кого может заинтересовать Ваш вопрос.

Comment: Ну вот Вам и ответ. Расстояние до отрезка может отличаться от длины перпендикуляра к прямой.

Comment: Ну, я просто дал тестирующую систему на случай, если понадобится. Конечно, я могу в следующий раз создать аккаунт на временном email для этого..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В качестве альтернативного решения, можно воспользоваться свойством скалярного произведение векторов, которое определит угол между вектором образованным точкой и одним из концом отрезка и вектором самого отрезка, иными словами,

пусть `P` точка, и `(P0, P1)` отрезок до которого требуется найти минимальное расстояние.

рассмотрим вектора

```
v = (P0, P1), w0 = (P, P0) и w1 = (P, P1)
```

Тогда если `dot(w0, v) <= 0` то угол между этими векторами тупой и следовательно перпендикуляр не лежит на отрезке (а находится слева от ближней до точки `P` точки `P0`) и тогда минимальное расстояние будет расстоянием между этими точками тоесть

```
S = dist(P, P0)
```

Аналогично для случая если `dot(w1, v) >= 0` получаем острый угол и положение точки `P` справа от `P1` и соотвественно минимальное расстояние

```
S = dist(P, P1)
```

где

`dist(A, B) = sqrt((B.x-A.x)^2 + (B.y-A.y)^2)`

а

`dot(A, b) = A.x*B.x + A.y*B.y`

Если оба условия выше не выполняются то основание перпендикуляра лежит на отрезке, следовательно в этом случае минимальным расстоянием будет длина этого перпендикуляра

```
S = distToLine(P, P0, P1)
```

вычисляемая как

```
distToLine(P, P0, P1) = ((y0-y1)*x + (x0-x1)*y + (x0*y1-x1*y0))/dist(P0, P1)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, будет очень полезно знать :) Хотя мне кажется, вектора лучше использовать в ситуациях немного посложнее. Ну и хорошо, у меня как-раз дальнейшей темой идут произведения векторов, так что ваш ответ как нельзя кстати :)

Comment: @ЕгорЛевоненко рад помочь :)

Comment: Что такое P2 в последней формуле?

Comment: @ValeriyVan это опечатка (исправил) имелось ввиду `dist(P0, P1)` тоесть это длина отрезка

Comment: Про скалярное произведение вы настолько не договорили, что ответ ваш скорее не корректный.

Answer (score 13):

Между расстоянием от точки до прямой, проходящей через две другие точки, и от точки до отрезка есть небольшая разница, правда?...

Вот, схематически - что здесь расстояние до отрезка (OB), а что - до прямой (OC), понятно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я бы делал так - посчитал бы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и, если *t<0*, взял бы *t=0*, если *t>1* - то *t=1*. И вычислил бы искомое расстояние как

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(надеюсь, при вводе (и выводе :)) формул не ошибся :))

Comment: @Igor Ой, да, спасибо, исправляю.

Comment: Спасибо. Но, как называется вторая данная вами формула? Ни разу её не видел в сети.

Comment: а от какой точки вы считаете расстояние ?

Comment: @ЕгорЛевоненко предлагаю - "Формула Хари". Можно с маленькой буквы.

Comment: _"если t<0, взял бы t=0, если t>1 - то t=1"_ - настораживает этот момент. Точно не надо всё равно проверять оба конца?

Comment: @ampawd от 0. Смысл - записываю уравнение точки отрезка параметрически; при t=0 это точка A, при 1 - точка B. Нахожу минимум, дифференцируя l^2. При t, выходящем за рамки отрезка, рассматриваю расстояние до ближайшей точки. Если не ошибся в выводе - то формулы вот они...

Comment: @Qwertiy Да вроде если ближайшее расстояние за точкой A, то до точки А ближе, чем до В. Соответственно, и наоборот... На рисунке t больше 1.

Comment: @Harry Иначе говоря, это можно заменить на min(Расст. до А, Расст. до Б)?

Comment: Нет, только если C *за пределами отрезка*.

Comment: @Harry, да, согласен.